# How to align ng-repeat checkboxes properly

Tags: html, checkbox, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to show ng-repeat data with properly aligned checkboxes as vertically. Below is the code snippet that I tried:

```
<table width="100%" class="table">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><label for="fruits" class="control-label">Select 
            Fruits</label></td></td>
            <td><label ng-repeat="fruit in MainCtrl.fruits">
            <input type="checkbox"> {{fruits}} 
            </label></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.fruits = {Apple,Mango};
});
```

It displays the rows horizontally like below:Apple Mango but I want it to display it vertically.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to style your checkboxes using CSS. You could set them to `display: block` and or `width: 100%`